# Sencha Touch 2 get record

Tags: sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2

In my controller, I want to get a random record from the localstorage and display in the view, how can I do that?

In my config I have:

```
stores: ['Items']
```

In my function I have :

```
var mystore = (this.getStores())[0];  
var index = this.getRandomInt(0, mystore.totalCount() -1);
var nextItem = mystore.getAt(index);
```

but it's stuck at the first line

Maybe there is an easier way?

Comment: what does `this` refer to in your code? If you're stuck at the first line, let's try logging what `getStores` returns for more detailed information. I'm afraid what you've provided is not enough...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since your store is called 'Items' i would:

```
var mystore = Ext.getStore('Items');
```

is the most reliable way to get the instance of the store.

Answer (score 1):

```
 mystore.totalCount()
```

should be

```
 mystore.getCount()
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's the function you shoud use

```
var getRandomRecord = function(store){
  var s = Ext.getStore('store');
  var r = s.getAt(Math.floor(Math.random()*(s.getCount()-1)));
  return r;
}
```

And you call it like this :

```
var randomRecord = getRandomRecord('Items');
```

Hope this helps